NextJS css only applied on page first refresh
I am using a yarn monorepo with expo + nextJS to export same UI / logic for both applications, and using react-native-ui-datepicker for a shared date pickers which works fine for both web and mobile, the only problem is that the when navigating from another page to a page that uses the date picker the css is all scrambled up, yet when I refresh the page it works but only on the page I refreshed when navigating I lose the css again.
What could cause such a problem?


